# lsof show number of open files that are more then what configured

Tags: linux, kernel, lsof, open-files, sysctl

we verify the file max as

```
[root@linux02 ~]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
500000
```

but when we run lsof we get

```
[root@linux02 ~]# lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/42/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
851635
[root@linux02 ~]#
```

how it can be that `lsof | wc -l`

show more open files then what is configured ?

Comment: check here... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476351/difference-between-ulimit-lsof-cat-proc-sys-fs-file-max

Comment: ... in particular, the second answer to that question, which answers this one.